# pymongo условные операторы и вычисления

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Допустим есть запись:

> {"name": "Tom", "numbers": [447, 851, 657, 945, 571]}

И искомые данные:

> [252, 651, 428, 841, 184]

Нужно составить запрос вывести все где: если от первого элемента в массиве numbers отнять первый элемент из искомого массива и результат более 200 то true и далее через "И" пройти остальные элементы.

Т.е. может так будет понятнее. Вывести все записи если:

```
(447 - 258 > 200) AND (851 - 651 > 200) AND (657 - 428 > 200) AND (945 - 841 > 200) AND (571 - 184 > 200)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно написать запрос для модуля pymongo на python.

UPD

Вот пару примеров если бы делали запрос на mongo клиенте со вставками javascript в фильтр:

> db.students.find(function (){var good=true; var my_numbers = [252,
>   651, 428, 841, 184]; for(var i=0;i<5;i++){if(this.numbers[i] -
>   my_numbers[i] <= 100){good=false;break}} return good})

Или чтоб было понятней, тот же самый запрос без цикла:

> db.students.find("(this.numbers[0]-252>100) &&
>   (this.numbers[1]-651>100) && (this.numbers[2]-428>100) &&
>   (this.numbers[3]-841>100) && (this.numbers[4]-184>100)")

Как записать в pymongo данные запросы со вставкой javascript. Оно не хочет принимать говорит что неверные типы.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант устроит?:

```
dct = {"name": "Tom", "numbers": [447, 851, 657, 945, 571]}

lst = [252, 651, 428, 841, 184]
res = all([x-y>200 for x,y in zip(dct['numbers'], lst)])
print(res) #False
```

UPDATE: После пояснений автора стало ясно, что вопрос по большому счету не имеет отношения к питону.

тогда нужно использовать что-то типа такого:

```
db.students.find({$and:[{this.numbers[0]-252>100}, { this.numbers[1]-651>100)},  {this.numbers[2]-428>100}, {this.numbers[3]-841>100},  {this.numbers[4]-184>100}]})
```

Comment: Вполне, только не соображу как его к pymongo привязать. Вот пример если делать через mongo клиент, т запрос работает на ура при таком варианте:

db.students.find("(this.numbers[0]-252>100) && (this.numbers[1]-651>100) && (this.numbers[2]-428>100) && (this.numbers[3]-841>100) && (this.numbers[4]-184>100)")

Но как заюзать в pymongo не пойму

Comment: UPDATE: Да что-то типо такого) Только там не много другой синтаксис, такой вариант работать не будет. Нашел другой через eval(javascript), чуть позже распишу

Answer (score 0):

strawdog, возможно верно описал если под корректировать. Но я не додумался как. За то нашел вот такой вариант:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import Code

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

documents = client.db.eval(Code("function(){return db.students.find('function(){return (this.numbers[0]-252>100) && (this.numbers[1]-651>100) && (this.numbers[2]-428>100) && (this.numbers[3]-841>100) && (this.numbers[4]-184>100)}').toArray()}"))
for document in documents:
    print(document)
```

Главное в функции find прописать еще одну функцию:

```
function(){return (this.numbers[0]-252>100) && (this.numbers[1]-651>100) && (this.numbers[2]-428>100) && (this.numbers[3]-841>100) && (this.numbers[4]-184>100)}
```

И если выводим более одного результат то после find() преобразовать в массив toArray() иначе вернет не совсем то.

P/s Если есть еще варианты более простые и более производительные. Опишите их.